# want to replace xfire for developing web service

Tags: java, web-services, xfire

I am using XFIRE  to develop soap services .
what is the other best alternative to XFIRE .
I want to replace XFIRE code from other best approach beca

Answer (score 0):

You can develop web services in different ways; [Apache CXF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_CXF) is the successor of XFIRE so perhaps it's the easiest path; there is also a [migration guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/xfire-migration-guide.html) . You can also using Spring-ws, but it depends if you are already familiar with spring and if you want/can adopt Spring in your project. Spring web services are contract first i.e. You start from the wsdl (or xsd in you prefer) and write the code that handle the data incoming; you can read more about this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#why-contract-first) 
Spring ws is very flexible and lets you handle the whole soap body allowing even to handle some ws client mistakes (in an ws implementation I handled two slightly different version of the ws with the same endpoint).

If you are writing web services, you are already using Spring and you are not afraid to manage the whole soap body you can choose Spring WS; if you want an easy migration path (because part of your team alreay knows xfire) apache cxf is the way to go.

Comment: right now we are using x-fire and we integrate soap services using x fire and we are initializing the services using spring . so I want to know better approach to implement  because when I am searching any content related xfire I get to know that it is not existing .
I am aware of spring .. so using Apache cxf is better or spring ws ?

can you give me small example to illustrate the same